# how to know which screen is open in blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, screen

how to know which screen is open/ in foreground in blackberry? In other words, can we get a name of the screen which is currently open in BB. It can include other app, call logs, messages etc. , not necessarily my APP. Can this be done? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

There are three methods in ApplicationDescriptor that can help you figure out the currently foregrounded app.  Getting to the Application object itself may be a little more difficult, but you can at least discover the ApplicationDescriptor.

```
ApplicationManager mgr = ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager();
final ApplicationDescriptor[] vApps = mgr.getVisibleApplications();
int foregroundId = mgr.getForegroundProcessId();
for(int i = 0; i < vApps.length; i++) {
   int id = mgr.getProcessId(vApps[i]);
   if(id == foregroundId) {
       // we have a winner!
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you mean:

```
if  (Application.getApplication().isForeground()) {
  Screen scr = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen()​;
}
```

Comment: I think `UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen()​` can only returns a screen that is pushed onto display stack by the UiApplication instance. `It can include other app, call logs, messages etc. , not necessarily my APP.` - Can this be done?